# In Visual Studio, how do I configure Rational Team Concert to use VS Code as the merge tool?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, mergetool, rational-team-concert

I'm using Rational Team Concert as source control tool, and I want to change the default merge tool. I really like the Visual Studio Code merge tool, but I don't know how to set it up to work with Team Concert.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

In Visual Studio, go to **Tools -> Options... -> Source Control -> Jazz Source Control -> Compare Tools**

In this screen you can set up your merge tool for Rational Team Concert.

[image]

1. Select an option for **Use an external compare tool instead of the default compare utility**.
2. For **External Compare Tool to Use**, select `<<Custom>>`
3. For **Location of Executable**, enter the path where you installed VSCode, e.g. 
   `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe`
4. For **Local Compare Arguments**, enter `--diff "${file2Path}" "${file1Path}"`

> **--diff** is an argument that tells to VSCode that you want to use the Merge Tool
>
> **${file1Path}** is the variable that holds the path of the first file.
>
> **${file2Path}** is the variable that holds the path of the second file.

5. For **Remote Compare Arguments**, enter `--diff "${file2Path}" "${file1Path}"`

---

Note that VSCode actually does not *support 3-way conflict comparison*. You can find more info here: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/5770

More related info:
http://blog.code-cop.org/2012/12/kdiff3-merge-tool-for-rtc.html,
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/versioncontrol